# Tooltipping Histograms: what's in the bin?

Tags: plotting, histograms, tooltip

## Question

Suppose you have two sets of data where each value has an associated label of some kind and for whatever reason you wish to histogram them. How can you use `Tooltip` to tell you the contents of the bin and which set they originate from. Obviously this is not meant for excessively large datasets.

## Example Data

```
(*make data*)
a = RandomInteger[10, 10];
b = RandomInteger[10, 10];

(*make labels*)
labels = RandomChoice[Alphabet[], 20];

(*make it explicit in the label which group data came from*)
aLabels = StringJoin["a: ", #] & /@ labels[[;; 10]]
bLabels = StringJoin["b: ", #] & /@ labels[[11 ;;]]

(*tooltip time*)
c = Tooltip[#1, #2] & @@@ Partition[Riffle[a, aLabels], 2];
e = Tooltip[#1, #2] & @@@ Partition[Riffle[b, bLabels], 2];

(*plot time*)
Histogram[{c, e}]
```

And you only get one label per bin :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool question. I can find a way to get `Histogram` to produce the correct tooltip internally, so I've resorted to a little formatting outside, then pointing `LabelingFunction` to the correctly formatted labels.

First I need to get the list of data points in each histogram bin:

```
{bins, vals} = HistogramList[a];
{aList, bList} = BinLists[#, {bins}] & /@ {a, b}
```

> {{{4, 0, 4, 0, 2}, {7, 5, 9, 9}, {10}}, {{3, 0, 1, 2}, {5, 6, 5, 7, 
>      7}, {10}}}

Then I use these lists to split the data point labels into the same list structure (there may be a more elegant / efficient way to do this):

```
labelLists = Function[{ds}, 
    Flatten[Pick[ds[[2]], ds[[1]], #] & /@ Union[#]] & /@ ds[[3]]
  ] /@ Transpose[{{a, b}, {aLabels, bLabels}, {aList, bList}}]
```

> {{{"a: a", "a: x", "a: e", "a: f", "a: v"}, {"a: e", "a: b", "a: b", 
>      "a: s"}, {"a: h"}}, {{"b: h", "b: t", "b: s", "b: f"}, {"b: c", 
>      "b: o", "b: s", "b: c", "b: v"}, {"b: e"}}}

In this format we can use the second argument (`#2`) to `LabelingFunction` to access the correct labels to show for a given histogram bar:

```
Histogram[{a, b}, {bins}, 
 LabelingFunction -> 
  (Placed[TableForm@{labelLists[[1 ;; #2[[1]], #2[[2]]]]}, Tooltip] &)
]
```

The extra jiggery-pokery in there (the `1;;#2[[1]]` etc) is so that overlapping bars display correctly:

[image]
[image]

Comment: very nice! Is there a way to possible make it a more like a table?

Answer (score 2):

The example data you gave has a highly overlapped area. Your real example might not have the same signature, but I would think that `PairedHistogram` might be a better visualization for the case. Anyway, no matter it is `PairedHistogram` or `Histogram`, you can use the customizability of `ChartElementFunction` to create your own histogram bars. The arguments that get fed in the `ChartElementFuncion` contain the information of data in each bin.

Here is an example:

```
f[{x_, y_}, data_, r__] := Tooltip[Rectangle @@ Transpose[{x, y}], data]
a = RandomInteger[10, 10];
b = RandomInteger[10, 10];
PairedHistogram[a, b, ChartElementFunction -> f]
```

then you can format the list however you want. There are a lot of ways to format lists in WL. Look up `TableForm` and there are related functions in the bottom of the doc.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `PairedHistogram` has its purpose, e.g. comparing two similar but distinct distributions. However overlaying can be nice to show similarly. The data from the example were random integers in [1,10] so naturally they overlapped a lot :)  I was also able to get `Tooltip` to display the list, which is sufficient for certain purposes, but it is much nicer to have formatting :D